# Problem with an infinite sum

Tags: numerics

I need to calculate a coefficient as follows

```
coef[a_, j_] := 
 E^(-a^2/2)
   NSum[(a/Sqrt[2])^n 1/Sqrt[((n - j)!) (j!)], {n, j, Infinity}]
```

This coefficient is an infinite sum over n and depends on a real number a and an index j.

I choose a = 2, and j = 19, i.e. coef[2,19], I get the outcome

```
1.94412*10^-6
```

but when I calculate coef[2,20] (j=20) the program runs forever.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Change definition to `coef[a_?NumericQ, j_?NumericQ] := 
 E^(-a^2/2)*NSum[(a/Sqrt[2])^n 1/Sqrt[((n - j)!) (j!)], {n, j, Infinity}]` and it will compute immediately.

Comment: @Alx: Thank you. So simple but definitely works.

Comment: @Alx Please could you explain why it works? Or, to put in a different way the question I'm really interested in, "What problem prevented the equation being solved, and how does your solution overcome that problem?"